# Display the thumbnail in this type of manner

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create thumbnails in this way. I tried but success rate is very less .  I am hoping that i can get the reply here

I prepared my views in form of diagram to understand you and photo links overs the link..

```
<div style="position:relative;"> 
    <ul id="image-gallery"> 
        <li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL1" /></a></li> 
        <li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL2" /></a></li> 
        <li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL3" /></a></li> 
        <li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL4" /></a></li> 
        <li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL5" /></a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: <div style="position:relative;">
<ul id="image-gallery">
<li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL1" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL2" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL3" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL4" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page-URL"><img src="IMAGE-URL5" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: by this hust iam not geting side bar also..

Comment: I am not get the side bar...  Just at now i changed the question.. the thing i want to view.. if you go that link you will come to know my thought

Comment: I make the small editing in my question to understand to every one i add my views in form by diagram

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your HTML

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

or this to your CSS file

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Check the view here : http://jsfiddle.net/aqgs7smk/1/